# Why is Aether shown battling a lion-headed giant?

Tags: greek, myth-identification

In this picture, the primordial god of the upper air, [Aether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aether_(mythology)), is depicted wrestling a lion-headed giant.

[image: Aether in battle with a lion-headed giant - Pergamon Museum]

Is there a myth/story for this anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lion-headed giant apparently is [Leon](http://www.theoi.com/Gigante/GiganteLeon.html), who, according to Ptolemy Hephaestion was slain by Herakles during the [Gigantomachy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giants_(Greek_mythology)#The_Gigantomachy):

> Herakles did not wear the skin of the Nemean lion, but that of a certain Leon (Lion), one of the Gigantes (Giants) killed by Herakles whom he had challenged to single combat.
>
> <sub>Source: Ptolemy Hephaestion, New History Book 5 (summary from Photius, Myriobiblon 190) (trans. Pearse) (Greek mythographer C1st to C2nd A.D.)</sub>

Unfortunately, I do not think a tale of Leon battling Aether survive.